# Hibernate CascadeType inside association annotation vs outside

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the difference between the CascadeType options inserted inside the @OneToMany annotation and those inserted inside @Cascade? which is the priority, is one of the two ignored?

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="page", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
    private List<Tag> tags;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference.

If OneToMany is a JPA annotation (javax.persistence.OneToMany) you can not use Hibernate 'cascade' inside. You have to use JPA cascade.

@Cascade annotation is specific to hibernate and not JPA.

When you write something like : CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, that mean that the cascade is used when you use hibernate method 'saveOrUpdate', so when you use hibernate methods to save, delete, ... objects use @Cascade annotation. If you use JPA methods use cascade inside @OneToMany annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade), is clear on this issues.
They espically recommand to use both in case of SAVE_UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in hibernate documentation we can use both cascadeType attribute and @cascade annotation :

```
@OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REPLICATE)
public Collection<Employer> getEmployers()
```

Comment: what is the meaning of more than one? and also what happens when you use hibernate syntax and JPA syntax at the same time?

Comment: @saimiris_devel In fact there's no difference between **JPA** and **hibernate** in some cases, such as calling : _persist_, _merge_ and _refresh_. But there is no _saveOrUpdate_ or _replicate_ in **JPA**. So **Hibernate** cover more than **JPA**. As you see in the example above they are using both **JPA CascadeType attribut** with _persist_, _merge_ in **OneToMany** and also **@cascade** for _replicate_ which is **hibernate** specific method.